# c# - prevent mousewheel scrolling in panel

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, panel, mousewheel

I want to prevent scrolling with the mousewheel in a panel with a scrollbar, how can ido this?

I have seen this suggested, but it's not working:

```
panel.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(MouseWheel);

void MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try inheriting your own Panel and just comment out the OnMouseWheel call:

```
public class WheelessPanel : Panel {
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // base.OnMouseWheel(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you provide a user with a scrollable control, why would you then prevent them from scrolling it? If you don't want them to scroll, don't give them scroll bars.

If I came across a UI like that I would dislike it and only use it if I absolutely had to.

Comment: If you want to use the mousewheel for zooming into a picture then you don't want to scroll the bars simultaneously. Still, you need the scrollbars to see all of the image and navigate useing these bars with the mouse.

Comment: @ChristianGold I'm having this exact problem right now. Zooming a PictureBox inside a panel and scrolling the panel. I need a way to seperate/disable the scrolling with the wheel.